# Port forwarding with SonicWALL doesn’t seem to work as expected

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have an AT&T modem that does passthrough to my [SonicWALL TZ105](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/products/TZ-105.html). However, I still have devices connected to the AT&T modem (therefore they have an address from the AT&T DHCP server). I’m fine with it like this as it separates the network.

- **TZ105 IP:** `192.168.168.168`
- **TZ105 WAN IP:** `My Static IP`
- **AT&T Modem IP:** `192.168.1.254`

I’m noticing this from my logs. I want to forward the ports for devices, like the Xbox.

```
Network Access  UDP packet dropped  192.168.1.86, 3074, X1  224.0.0.253, 3544   UDP Xbox Live (3544 UDP)
```

I figured this access rule would do it, but it doesn’t work. Ports don’t appear to be forwarding and there’s no traffic through that access rule.

- **From Zone:** WAN
- **To Zone:** WAN
- **Service:** Xbox Live
- **Source:** Xbox Consoles (WAN)
- **Destination:** Any

The service is just all the ports needed by Xbox Live. The source are any Xbox consoles on `192.168.1.x`.

Problem: Ports are not forwarding. There is no traffic through the access rule I set up.

Comment: Ports are not forwarding. There's no traffic through the access rule. I want to port forward for traffic that comes from the AT&T modem.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the practices illustrated in the following link:

https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw4535

Regards, 
Ravi

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.